# How to deploy custom Office 2007 themes to multiple users

Tags: deployment, ms-office, themes, customization, office-2007

Folks,

As part of our customization to MS Office 2007, we developed a number of custom theme files (.thmx).

The only way we now to deploy the custom theme is to copy them into %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes, for each user to allow the user to see the theme under his theme gallery drop down.

This is a not a problem for a few users but will be a problem for large deployment and when multiple users are using the same machine.

Please advice if there is a way to deploy themes to a large number of users.

Comment: yes, it is related to programming

Comment: You will rather get a problem with different OS/Office languages as the folder names are localized. You probably have to look up the the correct path in the Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I was asking about was as simple as copy the theme file to the following path :

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 12\

Comment: I have tested that and it works fine so far, I have implemented the installation using WiX, if someone is interested please contact me

Answer (score 0):

If you type "echo %APPDATA% in console you'll see that it is dependent on current logged on user so it shouldn't be a problem

next user will have a different username and a different appdata path

Comment: when we deploy to the current user, the theme file will only be available to that users, any other user who logs on the same machine will not see the themes !